# PHP stops executing with no error

Tags: php, session, buffer, server, execution

I'm administering a system used by around 100 users. Everything is working fine except for one user. When that user logs in, the source will only output about 70 lines og html and then just stop executing. PHP show no errors whatsoever, and nothing is shown in the error log. Errors is enabled in the script.

If i remove some lines, in the html, it will execute more PHP, but then still stop at about 70 lines in the source code.

This, as I said, only happens for one user.

Does anyone have an idea about what could be going wrong here?

Comment: Have you enabled errors?

Comment: Errors is enabled and the page is executing in under 0.5 seconds.

Comment: What is your code at line 69, 70 and 71 ?

Comment: The code is just a basic echo of a string <?php echo "test"; ?> . It only happens on one user. Works for all other users.

Comment: what is user id for that user

Comment: post some piece of code

Comment: @sanirranta the id is 831

Comment: Apart from the User ID, did you check the rest of the user profile for anything suspicious? It might help if you could post the code till the line PHP halts.

Answer (score 5):

if error is not displaying it means the error display or error reporting is off in php.ini you can turn it on by the following php functions

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors','On');
?>
```

place above functions in the starting of your file and it will output error if any occurs.